# Why does my Java program refresh every time I minimize the window?

Tags: java, swing

I am making a palace game to understand and get better at programming in Java. Though I have run into an issue where every time I minimize the screen the variable that is selecting the card image constantly refreshes. For example the Randomizing function I have makes the variable pick a card depending on a digit and then it displays it, but it changes every time I minimize the page and open it again. I tried to look for the answer to my problem but I couldn't find it. My code for what I am doing is in the previous question I asked. **My question is how do I stop my variables from refreshing every time minimize the page?**

**Edit: I just realized it also changes every time I move the window with my cursor if this helps.**

This is my randomize function:

```
public void randomizer() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int rand_int1 = rand.nextInt(15-1)+1;
        System.out.print(rand_int1);
        if (rand_int1 == 1) {
            setVariables(aceClover);

        }else if (rand_int1 == 2) {
            setVariables(twoClover);
        }else if (rand_int1 == 3) {
            setVariables(threeClover);
        }else if (rand_int1 == 4) {
            setVariables(fourClover);
        }else if (rand_int1 == 5) {
            setVariables(fiveClover);   
        }else if (rand_int1 == 6) {
            setVariables(sixClover);
        }else if (rand_int1 == 7) {
            setVariables(sevenClover);
        }else if (rand_int1 == 8) {
            setVariables(eightClover);
        }else if (rand_int1 == 9) {
            setVariables(nineClover);
        }else if (rand_int1 == 10) {
            setVariables(tenClover);
        }else if (rand_int1 == 11) {
            setVariables(jackClover);
        }else if (rand_int1 == 12) {
            setVariables(queenClover);
        }else if (rand_int1 == 13) {
            setVariables(kingClover);
        }else {
            System.out.println("Couldn't return any Cards!");
        }
    }
```

```
package MainClasses;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class DrawBoard extends Component{
    AllCards accessor = new AllCards();
    public void paint(Graphics g) { // function to draw onto the window
    Graphics2D g1 = (Graphics2D)g; // the component being used to access and write to the window
    g1.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()); // clears rectangle every frame
    g1.setBackground(Color.green); // sets background color
    accessor.randomizer();
    g1.drawImage(accessor.imageExtract, 100, 100, null);
    }   
}
```

If you need the rest of the code its in this question:

[The full code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59744072/why-am-i-getting-a-stackoverflowerror-when-getting-information-from-an-object)

It does have some minor changes because I fixed my previous problem all I did was make a new class and move the creation of those variables over to that class and removed them from my previous one.

Comment: It is because you are calling `accessor.randomizer();` in the `paint` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're calling the randomizer from within the paint method, and that method is called every time the gui gets minimized and restored, or any time it is resized.

solution: Don't do that, don't have any program logic within a painting method but instead have *only* painting code there.

Instead:

- Make the call from the class constructor which is only called once

Also:

- Don't extend Component but rather JPanel (don't mix AWT and Swing components)
- Paint within the JPanel's paintComponent method
- Call the super's painting method within the override `super.paint(g)` if you are overriding paint or `super.paintComponent(g)` if you override paintComponent. This allows "housekeeping" painting to occur, including the removal of "dirty" pixels.

Comment: Thank You for the quick reply!